# Can't SSH into Server on Google Cloud/Compute Engine

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've been trying to SSH into a server I have set up on google cloud, and have run into issues before but none quite like this. I have gotten error messages before saying it can't connect to the specific port... but now every time I try to SSH it never times out, and instead keeps loading/trying to connect (forever) until I stop it myself. Any ideas as to how I could solve this? I've already tried to make the boot disc bigger and delete some files through the gcloud command shell (that still works by the way) but nothing seems to be working.

Any suggestions??

Additionally when looking at the serial port I noticed that the apache server was failing to start and have been trying to restart it without success. Any possibility this is related?

[apache server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM7xL.png)

[vm config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cmSq.png)

[error loading message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4NcV.png)

[loading image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUlrR.png)

[server config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOJC8.png)

[api details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnlLp.png)

Comment: Thanks for your first a post.  Could you add a couple of things.  1 - The error messages you reference.  2 - A screenshot of the server configuration.  This could be an interesting problem, but we need more information to fix it  Thanks!

Comment: I added images as well as an error I noticed with the apache server.  Let me know what other details may be helpful!

Comment: dumb question: have you tried rebooting the vm?

Comment: I've tried starting and stopping the vm. And I also reset it a few days ago and had to reset-up the server. Didn't really change much though as it didn't fix anything and I'm having a similar problem again. I can always try again as a last resort - but wasn't sure if there was anything else I could do about it though.

Comment: From the screenshots you provided of the VM configuration seems fine. The only thing I would like to ask is if you are using an image for the boot disk from one that is offered by GCE or are you using a custom image? If you are using an image offered by GCE, can you tell me which one you  are using? I would like to try and reproduce the issue.